# How to create a loop thats includes a if statement

Tags: java, loops, methods

I'm attempting to create a method called "runExperiments()

the first step in the loop is to decrement a variable called "powerLevel" by a random number between 1 and 3 which is I have created a second method for which works.

**the next step which is where I am having problem is if the "powerLevel" can be reduced then I need a message containing the experiment number (starting at 1) should displayed, if not then a different message should be displayed and the remaining experiments should not be attempted.**

Then finally when all expierements have finished I need to display "Experiment run stopped" But I know how to do this section.

I have posted all the code below. The method is at the bottom. I have made a first attempt but I cannot seem to figure out the part in the bold. Any help or guidance would be fantastic. I'm not sure if I have used the correct type of loop either so that may be wrong as well.

```
public class SpaceRocket 
{
  private String name;
  private int maxPowerLevel;
  private int numberOfExperiments;
  private int powerLevel;
  private int decreasePowerLevel;

/**
 * returns maxPowerLevel
 */
  public int getMaxPowerLevel()
  {
  return this.maxPowerLevel;
  }

 /**
  * returns numberOfExperiments
  */
  public int getNumberofExperiments()
    {
  return this.numberOfExperiments;
    }

 /**
  * returns powerLevel
  */
  public int getPowerLevel()
 {
  return this.powerLevel;
 }

 /**
  * 
  * Causes execution to pause by time number of milliseconds
  * 
  */
 public void delay(int time)
 {
  try
  {
     Thread.sleep(time); 
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println(e);
  } 
 }

 /**
  *
  * return a random integer between 1 and 3 inclusive
  */
 public int randomInteger() 
 {
  java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
  return r.nextInt(3) + 1;
 }  

 public SpaceRocket(String aName, int aNumberOfExperiments)
 {
  this.name = aName;
  this.numberOfExperiments = aNumberOfExperiments;
  this.powerLevel = 0;
  this.maxPowerLevel = 15;
 }

 public boolean decrementPower(int adecreasePowerLevel)
 {
  this.decreasePowerLevel = adecreasePowerLevel;
  if(decreasePowerLevel > this.powerLevel)
  {
     this.powerLevel = 0;
     return true;
  }

  else 
  {
     this.powerLevel =(this.powerLevel - this.decreasePowerLevel);
     return false;
  }

 }

 public runExperiments()
 {
  for(this.powerLevel =(this.powerLevel - randomIntegar())
  {
     if(this.powerLevel

  }  
 }
```

Comment: I recall having seen multiple (at least 3) questions about this from you that got voted down and closed. I strongly urge you to try some basic java tutorials - because your question as it stands is "how do I write an if statement". **If the power level can be reduced, print something**. Surely such a question has been asked before.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, every time the loop runs, you want to decrease "powerlevel" by a random value, then display a message depending on whether powerlevel can be reduced.

Here are two approaches.

1) use an if statement in your for loop

```
for (conditions){
    if(powerlevel cannot be decremented){
        //display a messsage
        break;
    }
    // display a message
}
```

conditions could be iterating through all the experiments

2) use a while loop which checks whether powerlevel can be reduced in every loop

```
while(powerlevel can be decreased){
    //display a message containing the experiment number (starting at 1)
}
//display a different message
```